# How to destroy a C++ object manually?

Tags: c++, object

**Edit**
This was a senseless question as I am just realizing.

I am trying to make a simple tetris game using C++ and SDL2. I have a Tetromino class from wich I create tetromino objects.

When a bottom collision detected, I extract the position data of the four sub-cells of that tetromino. And store them on a seperate array of SDL_Rects. ( Which stores all the static blocks from multiple tetrominos piling at the bottom )

*( Tetris pieces are called tetrominos, and they consist of 4 squares arranged to create shapes of tetrominos. An SDL_Rect is basically a struct that holds x, y, width and height values for a rectangle. )*

After that point, I no longer have anything to do with that object. Since I would be creating many tetromino objects, I thought it would be a good practice to free the memory that they occupy.

I thought of calling the destructor explicity, but after a quick googling, it seems like calling the dtor manually is considered bad coding and all questions were related to dynamic memory handling for objects anyway.

**Is there a way to get rid of an object more conveniently?**

( Since the game will be running on a modern computer, I think the performance difference will be negligable. But I want to make it as lightweight as I can and this striked me as the most obvious unnecessary memory occupation. )

**TL:DR : I am creating multiple objects one at a time, after I am done with it, I want to get rid of the memory that it occupies before creating the next one. And I'd rather to avoid dynamic memory allocation.**

Comment: "*And I'd rather to avoid dynamic memory allocation.*" ... huh? If you're not already dynamically allocating the objects, then you must be either allocating them statically (in global variables) or on the stack. For stack variables, their memory will not be reused until they are *automatically* destroyed. So it's not clear what any of this means. Provide some code, where you show us how you're creating the objects, managing them, and the location you'd like to insert this "manual" destruction.

Comment: Please provide an example demonstrating what you are doing and what you want to achieve. Note that calling a destructor manually is in almost all situations wrong and often causing undefined behavior.

Comment: Are you asking how to delete objects from an array? How is the array created? Are you using a standard library container? Note that if your objects are just a struct with four `int` members then the objects don't need a destructor.

Comment: Good example of tl;dr. That is, there is too much to read and not much to get out of it.

Comment: I am now realizing that what I thought I want doesn't make much sense. I was planning to call a function to create a tetromino object every time previous one gets down. But of course I couldn't do that, instead I would reset the previous object do default and use it again. I am sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally there is only one teramino in game and array of the "pit", filled by fixed blocks. When tetramino touches any block in vertical direction, it gets conveted into blocks (after a grace period in classic game, so there is a fraction of second to "slide" sideways).

Doing it way you described turns game into incredibly complex task similar to Diablo "inventory tetris". E.g., sone games of that genre do not implement automatic sorting because of that.

Comment: Yeah I realized that way too late. Sorry and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You either use `new` / `delete` manually or `std::shared_ptr<Tetromino>` and `std::unique_ptr<Tetromino>` to create "automatic" memory management.

Objects created to stack are automatically free'd, like `Tetromino t`.

Sometimes it's also wise to recycle the objects so that instead of deleting objects you just move them to a list of recycled objects and use again. However, in my opinion this is useless with modern computers and in a game like this. There will be no performance benefit in practice.

Comment: stack should be automatic